# Getting error when try to add equations line by line in latex

Tags: align, amsmath

Hi there if any one can help. i want to add equations in latex. My equations are in fraction like precision= T_P/ T-P +f_n and so on in next line i have precision= T_P/ T-P +f_n and son  but when I compiled my code in pdf it gives me something which is so wrong if any one can help. I want my equations as define in this image  [image]

Here is my code

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{equation}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{align*} 

Precision =\frac{T_p}{T_p + f_p} \\  \\%
%%\end{align*} 
%%
Recall =\frac{T_p}{T_p + f_n} \\  
%%
Accuracy = \frac{T_p + T_n}{T_p + f_n+ f_p +T_n} 
%%
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can not have blank lines in math also (but unrelated) words such as `Precision ` should be marked as `\mathrm{Precision }`

Comment: missing `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble

Comment: I have added\mathrm and usepackage as well but nothing is working and I am getting this error now ! Paragraph ended before \align* was complete.

Comment: paragraph end is a blank line so that is the error mentioned in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just I add my proposal using `align*` or an array with the specific `interline` `[.6em]` (vertical space between the equation in the array). Peraphs it is better `[.7em]`, but you are free to choose the correct vertical space.

PS: I accept totally the comment of @David Carlisle on the use of `\mathrm` in math-mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\title{equation}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{align*} 
\mathrm{Precision} & =\frac{T_p}{T_p + f_p} \\
\mathrm{Recall} & =\frac{T_p}{T_p + f_n}  \\
\mathrm{Accuracy}& = \frac{T_p + T_n}{T_p + f_n+ f_p +T_n} 
\end{align*} 

\[
\begin{array}{ll}
\mathrm{Precision} & =\dfrac{T_p}{T_p + f_p}\\[.6em]
\mathrm{Recall} & =\dfrac{T_p}{T_p + f_n} \\[.6em]
\mathrm{Accuracy} & = \dfrac{T_p + T_n}{T_p + f_n+ f_p +T_n} 
\end{array}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]